# Plotting lag, jitter, bandwidth and frequency of topics, how to?

Tags: ros, rxplot, frequency, rostopic, bandwidth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to plot the mentioned data during an experiment for one or more topics and nodes.

Is there a way I can do that?

I tried rxplot but it wants a message's field.

I could go as far as writing a node to publish all this data as messages, but since this data is shown (not published) by a mixture of `rostopic` and `tfmonitor` how would I go at collecting the data itself?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59226/plotting-lag,-jitter,-bandwidth-and-frequency-of-topics,-how-to?/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started putting together some tools for measuring these types of statistics and then publishing them out over ros topics themselves. I also wrote an rviz modified camera plugin which performs the statistics without creating an additional camera socket connection.

I only implemented stats for latency and message loss, but it shouldn't be hard to add features to estimate jitter and bandwidth, too.

https://github.com/jhu-lcsr/lcsr_nettools

See the readme for more information and an example:

https://github.com/jhu-lcsr/lcsr_nettools/blob/master/readme.md

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-03-26**:
Thanks, I'll have a look.

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-03-26**:
Cloned your code but it refuses to build. What release did you base it on? rosbuild, catkin, rosmake?
I'm stuck on fuerte right now as groovy had all sorts of problems compiling on arm.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-26**:
It builds for me on fuerte, where is the build failing?

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-26**:
If you're trying to compile this for ARM, you might want to remove the deps from the manifest related to the rviz plugin, and then remove the rviz plugin from the CMakeLists. Really this package should be split into two: https://github.com/jhu-lcsr/lcsr_nettools/issues/2

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-03-26**:
No no i'm trying it on x86. i get a cmake fail on "moc_camera_display.cxx assuming it will be generated later" and

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-03-26**:
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib-1.8.10-py2.7.egg/roslib/gentools.py", line 318, in get_dependencies
raise MsgSpecException("Cannot load type %s.  Perhaps the package is missing a dependency."%(str(e)))

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-03-26**:
roslib.msgs.MsgSpecException: Cannot load type 'lcsr_nettools/TopicMeasurements'.  Perhaps the package is missing a dependency.

i manually checked every dependency in the manifest and I'm not missing any.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-26**:
If you're having trouble building the QT stuff (probably missing deps) and don't care about the rviz camera plugin, you can just remove the `add_subdirectory(rviz_plugins` from [CmakeLists.txt](https://github.com/jhu-lcsr/lcsr_nettools/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L30)

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-03-26**:
maybe you could join me on the ROS irc channel? I don't see us debugging this on answers :p

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-03-26**:
Anyway it's not rviz the problem, it's something in Generating ../msg_gen/cpp/include/net_tools/TopicStatistics.h

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-26**:
Ok, I'm on irc.oftc.net#ros

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-26**:
The issue was that the package was checked out under a different name.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-28**:
@Claudio Any luck?

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-04-09**:
@jbohren Is lcsr_nettools still maintained (last commit 2015)? Is it fuerte only or working with indigo as well? Otherwise: Are there alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think most of what you're asking for can be done with rostopic:

```
rostopic bw display bandwidth used by topic
rostopic hz display publishing rate of topic    
rostopic echo   print messages to screen
```

Code would be needed for the output of
`rostopic echo -p /topic`.
From this you can use any language of your choice to determine jitter in the timestamp of message.

Lag would have to be derived by some type of time difference.. so without more information I have no suggestions for that one.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-03-26**:
Mmm, I'm actually thinking about saving `rostopic` and `tf_monitor` output data to files, then parse and plot these files with matlab. But I hoped there was something easier.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2013-03-26**:
If your data is stamped, you could compute lag as the duration between the data timestamp and the time at which the subscriber callback is serviced. Make sure that your spinner thread is fast enough to not introduce significant measurement errors.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2013-03-26**:
Also, what are the expected/typical frequencies, lags, jitters in your application?

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-03-26**:
Frequencies below 10Hz, lags and jitters I don't know. That's why I want to plot them. I work on a fleet of vehicles controlled with ROS over wifi.
So I'm thinnking about running the core on a single machine to collect data for comparison, then progressively include more elements and save each step.

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2013-03-26**:
And eventually plot everything and see what comes out: if varying the number of robots affects lag and/or bandwidth, or what changes when scaling up the number of nodes. Or if the same nodes over different machines change the results and how compared to the same nodes on a single machine.

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2013-03-26**:
Frequencies in the order of 10Hz seem OK to monitor with ros topics and the existing tools.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-03-27**:
@claudio piping to a file is easy `rostopic echo -p /odom/pose/pose/position > myRobotLocation and the loading is easy in most languages (skip the first and last lines, and double check that each line of data ends with a newline)